# Query History on BigQuery Last 3 Months

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to look up query from history for example last 3 month, because from I know BigQuery just showing last 1 month query

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the BigQuery UI. You can go to the [BigQuery Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library). The query builder let's you select the **Time range**, see screenshot. Then use something like the below to search for the query you want (either on a keyword inside the query or all queries).

```
protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.getqueryresults"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobGetQueryResultsResponse.job.jobConfiguration.query.query:"keyword_inside_the_query"
timestamp>="2019-12-04T10:32:34.065+1100"
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `bq ls` [command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_ls).
For instance:

```
bq ls -j -all -n 10000
```

Will show up to 10000 jobs from all users or all datasets. Also, you could use the `--min_creation_time` flag as it'll list jobs created after that millisecond timestamp.

Hope it helps.